# How to read one single char in Rust?

Tags: char, rust, stdin

I'm trying to build a game that reads characters from input in order to move the player. Every example I've seen reads complete lines, which means I have to press a key and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, clearly a no-go. How can I get just one single char, without waiting for any other char?